# XSLT adds unnecessary namespaces, how to get rid of them?

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0, xml-namespaces

I process this XML file:

```
<z/>
```

by this XSLT 2.0 stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet
  xmlns:xsl = "http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns = "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:html = "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:data = "http://portonvictor.org/ns/misc"
  version = "2.0"
  exclude-result-prefixes = "data html">

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:variable name="x">
      <data:doc>
        <xsl:copy-of select="*"/>
      </data:doc>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:copy-of select="$x/*/*"/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Command line:

```
saxonb-xslt -xsl:error.xslt -s:error.xml
```

The resulting output is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><z xmlns:data="http://portonvictor.org/ns/misc"/>
```

It contains unnecessary `xmlns:data` namespace (even despite of I have `exclude-result-prefixes`). What is the easy way to get rid of such unnecessary namespaces?

The above toy example is a simplified [real code of my free program](https://github.com/vporton/htmlsplit), where I process an input XHTML file in several stages, first creating `<data:doc>` elements and then processing them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, your `$x` variable contains an element in the `xmlns:data="http://portonvictor.org/ns/misc"` namespace  - and the element that you copy is a descendant of that element.

When you copy an element, you also copy all the namespaces that are in-scope for that element.

You'll see a different result if you change:

```
<xsl:copy-of select="$x/*/*"/>
```

to:

```
<xsl:copy-of select="$x/*/*" copy-namespaces="no"/>
```

Not sure how well this applies to your real problem.

Comment: I tried to rewrite my XSLT script with added `copy-namespaces="no"` wherever it may seem useful. This has not helped. Please join development of this my free utility, it is useful for the community.

Comment: My "real code" generates superfluous namespaces even if I add `copy-namespaces="no"` to **every** `xsl:copy` and `xsl:copy-of` element

Comment: Oh, it works, just I idiotically wrote `copy-namespaces="yes"` instead of `copy-namespaces="no"`

Comment: To add to the explanation: `exclude-result-prefixes` prevents namespaces being copied from the stylesheet when literal result elements are evaluated. `copy-namespaces='no'` prevents namespaces being copied from the source document when `xsl:copy` and `xsl:copy-of` instructions are evaluated. In both cases this only works if the namespace is not used in any element or attribute name; if the namespace is used, it will be added back to the result tree by the namespace fixup process.

Comment: @porton Note also that this is a purely cosmetic issue; a redundant namespace declaration is semantically meaningless and should make no difference to the target application.